# What is the simplest way to run Groovy through a web server like Apache+PHP?

Tags: java, macos, web-applications, groovy

On a Mac with JDK and all Groovy necessities installed, how can Groovy files be served through a web server through the browser like PHP and Apache?

What else do I need to have installed? (Web Server, etc.)
How can I get that web server to show Groovy like Apache does with PHP?

Before getting into Grails I am interested in learning and running Groovy alone. I want to make a simple site with just Groovy code, replacing PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any experience writing web application in Java?

Comment: You cannot embed JRE into Apache, therefore Apache will not run Java just like Apache MOD_PHP. The FCGI model would also not work because Java takes 10-100 times more RAM than PHP and the startup time is a lot slower (with Groovy it's 0.2s). The way is to run it on Grails and make reverse proxy on Apache. Instead of Apache you can use Varnish Cache. Cache not only serves static content faster (taking load from JRE), but also caches pages generated by Grails (you can use HTTP headers to control it from Groovy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write servlets in Groovy:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets

You need to deploy them in a Java web container, like Tomcat, for example.

Comment: Thank you.
Do you think that the result would be faster than using Grails and its magic functionalities?

Comment: I would say neither of them is faster, because both are build on Java servlet technology, so at runtime, you have servlets in both case.

Comment: @Phil Modulo that Grails has more going on under the covers than a plain Groovy servlet; I'd expect Groovy servlets to be faster than Grails, but only marginally.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

Groovy is a language that runs in a JVM. To get it to run, you need something like Tomcat or another application server to run the code.

This should get you started: http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7.

Comment: Technically not really true, as you could use CGI. Shouldn't, but could.